# How much force from the charges in a gram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

In *Molecules*, Theodore Gray says,

> But if you could separate all the protons in that piece [1 gram] of iron from all the electrons and put all the protons on one side and all the electrons of the other side of a one-centimeter gap, the attractive force between them would be strong enough to hold up a cube of iron about eight *miles* on edge, or a good-sized mountain.

<sub>*Molecules*, p. 137</sub>

I decided to do the calculations myself. A gram of iron [has](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=atoms+in+a+gram+of+iron) $1.078\times10^{22}$ atoms. Multiplying by the atomic number of iron, that [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.078%C3%9710%5E22+*+26) $2.8028\times10^{23}$ protons in a gram of iron. The [charge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=charge+of+proton) of a proton is $1.602\times10^{-19}$ coulombs. Multiplying that by the number of protons [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.602%C3%9710%5E-19+coulombs+*+2.8028%C3%9710%5E23) $44,900$ coulombs of charge. Since the charges of the electrons must equal the ones of the protons, that also gives $44,900$ coulombs of charge on the electrons. [Plugging](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coloumbs+law&assumption=%7B%22FS%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%7B%22CoulombsLaw%22%2C+%22F1%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22CoulombsLaw%22%2C+%22Q2%22%7D+-%3E%2244%2C900++C%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22CoulombsLaw%22%2C+%22Q1%22%7D+-%3E%2244%2C900+C%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22CoulombsLaw%22%2C+%22r%22%7D+-%3E%221+cm%22) that into Coulomb's Law gives $1.812\times10^{23}$ newtons of force. Now in Earth's gravity, that force [equates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.812%C3%9710%5E23+newtons&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%22%22) to a mass of $1.848\times10^{22}$ kilograms. [In iron terms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.848%C3%9710%5E22+kilograms+of+iron), that is a cube 825.8 miles on edge, much larger than 8. Is Gray wrong, or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: This comment does not answer the question but in the book the separation is given as $1\,\rm cm$ and the mass of the mountain as $7.5\times 10^{15}\,\rm kg$.  The diagram also shows the charge spread out on two parallel condenser plates of an area the same as that of the base of a mountain, the mountain being upside down in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

What you calculated is the force between nuclei and electrons separated by an inch. However, it is not clear what the author calculated. Maybe it was the force from the resulting dipole, and one can only guess what distance the author had in mind. Anyway, a distance of one inch between a charge and a 13-mile-sized cube does not make sense.

Comment: What the author meant was that the *force* between the charges is sufficient enough to *hold up* an iron cube 13 miles on edge

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan : Maybe so, but that does not follow from the text of your post. Maybe you should quote the author more directly.

Comment: Seems I slightly misquoted: a 1 cm gap with an 8 mile cube. that makes the difference even bigger...